# Change URL with replaceState() and load to same site and no changed url

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I change URL with window.history.replaceState(), but when I wanna refresh the page with replaced URL, the page doesn't exist (logic, I changed URL).

Can I do, that user will see my changed page and when he refreshed the page (on changed url), it'll locate to the same page and no the new url page, that doesn't exist.

Example:

localhost/admin/index.php

-> user see -> localhost/ -> user refresh site

-> site itself will load to localhost/admin/index.php and no localhost

Comment: It will be much easier to configure the server so it will do it by itself. If you are using Apache the simple `.htaccess` file with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) should do the job.